# Loading data from service using $routeParam

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to load a group of messages depending on an ID that is part of the app's route. The routeParams object appears to be a promise, and I'm not sure how to set it up so that it waits until the routeParams object have loaded to load the group of messages:

```
var current = Messages.rest({m_gid:$routeParams.gid}).query({}, function () { 
    $scope.messages.current = Messages.messages.current = current.data;
});
```

I'm sure that this is simple, I'm just at a loss...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `$routeChangeSuccess` [event](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route).

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous){
    //do work with $routeParams here
});
```